# concatenate auto field with string using django

Tags: python, django, django-1.6, autofield

I want to generate an unique string in my django1.6 application. For that I want to concatenate the primary key (autofield) with the string. My code is

```
class Complaints(models.Model):
    gid     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    complaint_no    = models.CharField(max_length=50)       
    status      = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%s %s' % (self.gid, self.complaint_no))

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):     
        self.complaint_no = '%s%d' % (self.complaint_no,self.gid)
        super(Complaints, self).save(force_insert, force_update)    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'complaints'
        verbose_name = "complaints"
```

But I got the error message as

TypeError at /callcentre/register/

%d format: a number is required, not NoneType

Please help me to solve this error!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create field id as charfield e.g.

`string_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='file')`

2. Make a function that make string id when the model is saved.

   `def save(self):
           new_id = self.id

           self.string_id = str(new_id) + '_dot'
           super(YourModelName, self).save()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super()` first.

As you can read in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys):

> There’s no way to tell what the value of an ID will be before you call save(), because that value is calculated by your database, not by Django.

When you call `super().save()`, the database engine calculates the `id` (or `gid` in your case, but please reconsider using the provided `id`) and thus allows you to use it. Before that it is `None`.

You may check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234917/django-how-to-get-self-id-when-saving-a-new-object) as well.

Comment: Thank You  @dsoosh  ,  But if we put the super() first the complaint_no will not update with the corresponding id. for that I have to do one more save().

Comment: @Anju: it would, if you had not overriden the `id` AutoField with your `gid` field (which definition is the same as id's, thus being redundant in this case), the superclass' `save()` method would've been invoked and the `id` value would have been calculated and available in your model's `save()` function.