# use unique id in django model custom save

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create unique slugs from persons names, which will have obvious duplicates.  My idea is to add the id to the slug as a unique identifier.  The problem is that the unique id is not generated until the save completes.

This is what I tried:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if getattr(self, 'name', True):

            if not self.pk:
                matching_slugs = Entity.objects.filter(slug=slugify(self.name))
                print matching_slugs
                if len(matching_slugs) > 0:
                    self.slug=slugify(self.name+' temp')
                elif len(matching_slugs) == 0:
                    self.slug=slugify(self.name)
        super(Entity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slug=slugify(self.name+' '+str(self.id))
        self.save()
```

I get the error:

> maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

I'm thinking this is not the best way to do this.

**How can I make names unique on save?**

Comment: Just delete `self.save()`

Comment: But why you do not use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#slugfield with `unique=True`

Comment: Do you specifically need the slug to be `name` + `pk` or do you just need a unique slug? It may help if you tell us how you want to use this slug.

Comment: @AndMar is right that the `self.save()` is the cause of the recursion error, but it looks like you want to use `self.id` which isn't set until the object is first saved so I can see why you are trying to save it twice. This post may help with saving an object twice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14236946/1051031

Answer (score 3):

May be you can use simple construction?:

```
import uuid


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
          self.slug = "%s.%s" % (self.name , uuid.uuid4())
    super(Entity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. It Saved me for another purpose. Nice Question, Nice Answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the save() to be:

```
    super(Entity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.slug=slugify(self.name+' '+str(self.id))
    super(Entity, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```